# PYX12 packages | convert EDI X12 to JSON

Tags: python, edi, x12

Does the PYX12 packages Python package convert the below EDI X12 format like 850, 856, 810, 855, 856 from EDI to JSON format.

I am unable to find any info on this.

Thanks
Yatan